# How can I troubleshoot the cause of a failed google sign in on Android?

Tags: android, oauth

For my Android app, signing in with google is failing. All I can see is that the result of trying to sign in and get an OAuth token is GoogleSignInStatusCodes.SIGN_IN_FAILED

Is there a way I can get more detailed information about why the sign in failed?

Edit: I do not have a stack trace because no exception is being thrown, and I am not using Firebase because the only things my app needs from Google is a few of the APIs.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem. A stack trace or log would be helpful. Also, are you using firebase ?

Comment: how you generate SHA-1. from cmd or android studio?

Comment: I generated the SHA-1 hash from within the android studio terminal.